# Why do people use the word "くそ"?

Tags: culture

I don't know if it's written in hiragana but I have knowledge that kuso means "shit". Why do kids use that term so much? Isn't it offensive or considered a bad word? 
I am asking this because it's not normal in European countries (where I am at least) for kids to use often bad words.

So, isn't it offensive?

Answer (score 3):

くそ is a coarse word which can also be vulgar, but it is not the same as saying 'shit' in English, which is a stronger word. It depends on how it's used (context, tone, etc) and it's more likely to be used by males than females. It could be as mild as 'damn' depending on the usage, but I'd say it's generally somewhere between 'damn' and 'shit', and closer to the 'damn' side. If that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

くそ is curse word, we don't learn it's forbidden word in childhood. So we don't have such education, if you watch japanese tv,  you can hear the exact words without sound effects.